# TexLive 2011, MacTeX and file permissions

Tags: fonts, mactex

I've recently had occasion to upgrade three Mac machines to texlive 2011 using the package at MacTex. All the machines had different vintages of Tex already installed on them, though all had been installed from packages on the MacTex site - one had texlive 2010, one had an even older version of MacTex. It seems that all three have different permissions problems which lead to problems trying to run latex documents using locally installed fonts -- in all cases, Latex cannot find the font although `sudo updmap --listmaps` shows that the map files are there and known about.

The locally installed fonts are in the user's own Library under a texmf tree. Previously I would just run `sudo updmap --enable Map ...` and this would all work. Now it doesn't -- `updmap` does add the map file, but Latex still cannot find the fonts.

Curiously, all three installations have different file permissions on the texlive directly in the user's Library folder - one has read-write access, one has read access and another does not permit access at all!!!

Is texlive inheriting something from somewhere strange? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all three Macs running the same OS vintage?

Comment: Hi Mico, yes, all three are running the latest version of Lion (the upgrade to Lion is what prompted me to upgrade the TeX versions on all three).

Comment: After adding the .map information (via `updmap`), did you remember to run `texhash`?

Comment: @Mico: But `updmap` supposedly does run `texhash`, unless you specifically ask it not to.

Comment: Hi Mico. Yes, I ran texhash after each call to updmap. What is strange to me is that the texlive directory permissions differ between the different installs - though this may be a red herring. I've verified that the right version of tex is being used, but texlive just doesn't seem to want to find the fonts. It finds the style files in the local texmf tree (Library/texmf/tex)

Comment: I do wonder why you run `updmap` under `sudo` at all? You shouldn't need superuser privileges to update the user's private data, and root gets to own any files created, which might not be a good idea. I would run `sudo chmod -R +w Library/texmf` followed by `sudo chown -R username Library/texmf`, and then run `updmap` once more (without the `sudo`). But whether this will solve the problem I don't know. There is not enough data to go on.

Comment: As it stands, I don't see how we can answer this. We don't have a full set of details about the systems, and even then the most obvious solution is to 'tidy up' the permissions.